# Is it safe to move boot partition and increase the / (root) space?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mysql, gparted, disk-management

[image]

I have dual boot machine (Windows 10 + Ubuntu 14.04) and disk status as above.

I want to insert a very large data in MySQL db which >100G. For this, I think I have to increase my / partition using unallocated 100G of space.

In given scenario, A boot partition is in the way. So my questions are-

1. Is that the boot partition for Windows 10?
2. Should I move the boot partition and increase / space?
3. Is there any other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the correct terms.

You want to increase `/`, not `/root`.

For some reason you have two EFI partitions: sda3 and sda6.

Probably you made a mistake, while installing Ubuntu and created an extra fat32 partition.

It looks like sda6 is not used at all. EFI partition is common for Windows and Ubuntu. You can look into it and see what is there.

Anyway you do not need two EFI partitions. You can delete sda6, if there is no Windows EFI in it. I very much doubt that there is something. It looks empty.

Even if there is Windows EFI, you can boot with Windows installation disk and fix Windows boot from there. sda3 is enough for both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: How can I check whether the /dev/sda6 is empty or not?

Comment: I think you can delete that extra `boot` partition safely. To be 100% sure, mount it and look what is there. But according to the size used it must be empty.

Comment: Run `sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt` and see what is in /mnt directory. If there is nothing, it means it is empty.